# Repelling charges and current flow

Tags: current, electron, electrostatic

The electrostatic force between two like charges is repelling. This concept is fairly clear to me with Coulomb's law and electric fields. So two electrons will repel each other. Given this statement, how come the electrons flow together in a current? shouldn't they be repelling each other and running in opposite directions? I guess that they are attracted by the free protons but does it mean that this attraction force is bigger than the repelling one? so the net force will be in direction of the protons? it is not crystal clear to me.

Comment: They do. But they are surrounded by positive charges, as well. Matter is pretty much neutral. Are you looking for some kind of computation? Or what, exactly? It sounds to me like you want to spend time at a whiteboard with a physicist for a few hours. However, there is a very good textbook that just ***might*** be right up your alley for this: **Matter & Interactions** by Chabay and Sherwood, 4th edition or later (3rd is good, though.)

Comment: Awsome thanks. Yes actually i am trying to really understand how it goes. If there is any math to fully describe this, i would be very happy to study it. Maybe it will come later in the course: i am following a course on electromagnetism.

Comment: Found explanation in this article: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/631015/if-an-electron-is-repelled-by-another-electron-how-is-it-that-we-get-an-electric

Comment: Well, that doesn't cover everything. And it doesn't really give enough of a picture, either, to really have a "fuller feel." But if you like that, then it's good enough. The Bloch Theorem is worth a moment when up for it.